# Web Font doesn't show on other pc's

Tags: html, css

I'm using Open sans on my website and for some reason the website shows "Open sans" only on my pc. I tried to access it from 2 other pc's and there's not "Open Sans". What did I miss?
*on smartphones it's showing ok

Here's the website: http://denea.comeze.com

Here's the css that responds for the font:

```
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


       * {
 font-size: 100%;
 font-family: 'Open sans';
}
```

Comment: I don't know why it works on your computer (maybe you have Open Sans installed locally?) but there's an error in your stylesheet: you can't have `<link>` elements in a stylesheet. Either use the `@font-face` syntax, or put the `<link>` in the head of the html file.

Comment: @MrLister Yes I have it installed locally. Placed <link> in index.html, worked. Now I know more, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

add that line to you html file, not in your css file
should be added in the `<head>` section of your site